# Looping problems with python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to loop a battle menu. Although it's not finished yet, I'm having problems looping it. I would like the menu to keep looping until myhp, or hp is lower than 0. so i used "while myhp > 0 or hp > 0:"

it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```
def fightmode(name, hp, dmg, gold):
print '\n\n\nYou are in a fight with %s' %name
print '%s has %sHP' %(name, hp)
while myhp > 0 or hp > 0:
    hp = hp - mydmg
    print '\n\t1. Attack \n\t2. Guard \n\t3. Run away.'
    opt1= ''
    allowed = ["1", "2", "3"]
    while opt1 not in allowed:
        opt1 = raw_input("\nWhat will you do? ")
        if opt1 == "1":
            print "You have inflicted %d damage on %s. %s's HP is %s" %(mydmg, name, name, hp)
if myhp > 0 :
    print"myhp"
if hp > 0 :
    print"theirhp"
```

Comment: Explain what "does not work" means.  What do you want it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Please reformat your code so it is displayed as valid Python. Don't use tabs but four spaces for indention.

Answer (score 2):

nevermind, I think I got it. I changed "or" to "and" and it seems like it's working.
Was this the right method?

Comment: Yes, it is. Your while loop needs to run until *either* drop below 0, not until *both* do.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you need `myhp` OR `hp` to be true for the while loop to continue going.
So if one of them drops to 0 and thus "goes False" the other one is still going to be true and keep the loop going.

So how can you do something about that?? (You already guessed right... Use `and` instead!)

So `while myhp > 0 or hp > 0:` should be `while myhp > 0 and hp > 0:` (Note that the `or` is exchanged for `and`!)

Answer (score -1):

Because *while* loop lopping until Boolean expression is **true** and stops after expression get **false**

So you need to write `while myhp < 0 or hp < 0:`